# Check for a substring in MySQL and return a value based on it

Tags: mysql, sql, string, substring

I have an SQL query that returns the following values:

```
BC - Worces
BC Bristol
BC Central
BC Torquay
BC-Bath
BC-Exeter
BC-Payroll
```

So, we have some BC with just a space, some with a dash and some with a dash with spaces on either side. When returning these values, I want to replace any of these BC variants with "Business Continuity: " followed by Bath, or Exeter etc.

Is there a way of checking what value is returned and (I'm assuming in a separate column) returning a field based on it? If every iteration was the same, I could just use Trim, but it's the variation that's throwing me out.

Comment: are the only variations using " " and "-" characters?

Comment: what about nested replace statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a case on the select

```
CASE WHEN Left(`colname`, 5) = 'BC - ' THEN CONCAT('Business Continuity: ', SUBSTRING(`colname`, 6))
     WHEN Left(colname, 3) = 'BC ' THEN CONCAT('Business Continuity: ', SUBSTRING(`colname`, 4))
     WHEN Left(`colname`, 3) = 'BC-' THEN CONCAT('Business Continuity: ', SUBSTRING(`colname`, 4))
     ELSE `colname`
END as `colname`
```

Comment: This is the most solid solution as it is looking at just the first 3-5 first characters. The only negative is it uses a case but it probably won't matter much.

Comment: @tmutton - Is case bad practice?

Comment: @tmutton please explain why a case is a negative in this answer.

Comment: @Fred Speed. But it probably won't matter.

Comment: I'm only returning 62 results. Any impact is negligible.

Comment: Exactly so not an issue. Glad you got the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html) function along with `CASE` statement for this.

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN `col_name` LIKE 'BC %' THEN REPLACE(`col_name`, 'BC ', 'Business Continuity: ') 
    WHEN `col_name` LIKE 'BC-%' THEN REPLACE(`col_name`, 'BC-', 'Business Continuity: ')
    ELSE `col_name`
    END as `col_name` FROM `table_name`;
```

Comment: And what if a town name has BC in it? Not a solid solution.

Comment: @tmutton: Note the string literal in the `LIKE` clause `'BC %'`. You can see that `%` is only after `BC<space>`. So it will match all occurrences of entries that start with `BC<space>` only. [Ditto with `BC-`]. And I don't think there is any town named just _BC_ ;)

Answer (score -1):

*Not tested

```
select 'Business Continuity:' + SUBSTRING(REPLACE(fieldname, 'BC - ', 'BC-'), 4) from table;
```

1. Replaces all instances of 'BC - ' with 'BC-'.
2. Substrings everything from 4 characters onwards ie 'BC-' and 'BC '

Comment: Was about to post this myself. Tested, and it works.

Comment: The concern is to remove those three instances. Once you remove them you are left with what you need then just tac on the string.

Comment: Only works, if there's no space, dash or BC in the remainder

Comment: @dnoeth i dont understand. It strips out the pieces it needs to, in the cases mentioned by OP. can you explain your comment?

Comment: Should be fixed now.

Comment: that said, can you name a town in england that has B and C next to each other?

Comment: This just returns 0 on everything?

Comment: Very true but not 100% solid. My update take everything from the fourth character then removes '- '. It will work.

Comment: @BFWebAdmin The field returns 0?

Comment: Put fieldname and table in quotes?

Comment: This is still very flaky.

Comment: @Fred Of course it is Fred. It's not a solid answer.

Comment: @BFWebAdmin Too late but updated answer in one line.